# NiFi SelectHiveQL processor - transfer relationship not specified

Tags: apache-nifi

let me know if I am missing anything stupid here, all the relationship is properly defined in the flow what will happen in success and failure.

But when I run my flow with the same query which is working fine from another client is through "transfer relationship not specified" after 1 or 2 min of query execution.

Please help me on this, below is the log -

```
19:47:39 UTCERROR298edfeb-0173-1000-ffff-fffffab073a1
gcp6207dev05.example.com:9091SelectHiveQL[id=298edfeb-0173-1000-ffff-fffffab073a1] SelectHiveQL[id=298edfeb-0173-1000-ffff-fffffab073a1] failed to process session due to StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=8caacace-4539-4d2b-9805-fec4c42732dd,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1594824838301-13, container=default, section=13], offset=24332, length=2428],offset=0,name=170f4a2c-e72d-405e-80eb-786031b6861d.0.csv,size=2428] transfer relationship not specified; Processor Administratively Yielded for 1 sec: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.FlowFileHandlingException: StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=8caacace-4539-4d2b-9805-fec4c42732dd,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1594824838301-13, container=default, section=13], offset=24332, length=2428],offset=0,name=170f4a2c-e72d-405e-80eb-786031b6861d.0.csv,size=2428] transfer relationship not specified
19:49:59 UTCERROR298edfeb-0173-1000-ffff-fffffab073a1
gcp6207dev05.example.com:9091SelectHiveQL[id=298edfeb-0173-1000-ffff-fffffab073a1] com.slb.it.data.dataplatform.nifi.nifi_select_hive.processors.SelectHiveQL$$Lambda$794/1582320685@66d3eb5e failed to process due to StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=fcc7293b-b97f-4e2c-81f8-75d684577b04,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1594824453797-6, container=default, section=6], offset=8441, length=2428],offset=0,name=aa00944a-f497-4814-97c6-b7287326fb01.0.csv,size=2428] transfer relationship not specified; rolling back session: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.FlowFileHandlingException: StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=fcc7293b-b97f-4e2c-81f8-75d684577b04,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1594824453797-6, container=default, section=6], offset=8441, length=2428],offset=0,name=aa00944a-f497-4814-97c6-b7287326fb01.0.csv,size=2428] transfer relationship not specified
19:49:59 UTCERROR298edfeb-0173-1000-ffff-fffffab073a1
gcp6207dev05.example.com:9091SelectHiveQL[id=298edfeb-0173-1000-ffff-fffffab073a1] SelectHiveQL[id=298edfeb-0173-1000-ffff-fffffab073a1] failed to process session due to StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=fcc7293b-b97f-4e2c-81f8-75d684577b04,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1594824453797-6, container=default, section=6], offset=8441, length=2428],offset=0,name=aa00944a-f497-4814-97c6-b7287326fb01.0.csv,size=2428] transfer relationship not specified; Processor Administratively Yielded for 1 sec: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.FlowFileHandlingException: StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=fcc7293b-b97f-4e2c-81f8-75d684577b04,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1594824453797-6, container=default, section=6], offset=8441, length=2428],offset=0,name=aa00944a-f497-4814-97c6-b7287326fb01.0.csv,size=2428] transfer relationship not specified
19:49:59 UTCERROR298edfeb-0173-1000-ffff-fffffab073a1
gcp6207dev05.example.com:9091SelectHiveQL[id=298edfeb-0173-1000-ffff-fffffab073a1] Issue processing SQL select *,CASE WHEN ing_tsp > 20200715143241 THEN '\\N' ELSE '\\N' END AS DPLATFORM_OPERATION_PROCESS_ID ,CASE WHEN ing_tsp > 20200715143241 THEN '\\N' ELSE '\\N' END AS INDICATOR from database.table_name due to Error during database query or conversion of records..: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: Error during database query or conversion of records.
19:49:59 UTCERROR298edfeb-0173-1000-ffff-fffffab073a1
gcp6207dev05.example.com:9091SelectHiveQL[id=298edfeb-0173-1000-ffff-fffffab073a1] Unable to execute HiveQL select query select *,CASE WHEN ing_tsp > 20200715143241 THEN '\\N' ELSE '\\N' END AS DPLATFORM_OPERATION_PROCESS_ID ,CASE WHEN ing_tsp > 20200715143241 THEN '\\N' ELSE '\\N' END AS INDICATOR from database.table_name for StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=738dff8a-9149-46ca-beef-2976bb997d9e,claim=,offset=0,name=aa00944a-f497-4814-97c6-b7287326fb01.0.csv,size=0] due to Error during database query or conversion of records.; routing to failure: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: Error during database query or conversion of records.
19:49:59 UTCERROR298edfeb-0173-1000-ffff-fffffab073a1
gcp6207dev05.example.com:9091SelectHiveQL[id=298edfeb-0173-1000-ffff-fffffab073a1] com.slb.it.data.dataplatform.nifi.nifi_select_hive.processors.SelectHiveQL$$Lambda$794/1582320685@66d3eb5e failed to process due to StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=fcc7293b-b97f-4e2c-81f8-75d684577b04,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1594824453797-6, container=default, section=6], offset=8441, length=2428],offset=0,name=aa00944a-f497-4814-97c6-b7287326fb01.0.csv,size=2428] transfer relationship not specified; rolling back session: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.FlowFileHandlingException: StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=fcc7293b-b97f-4e2c-81f8-75d684577b04,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1594824453797-6, container=default, section=6], offset=8441, length=2428],offset=0,name=aa00944a-f497-4814-97c6-b7287326fb01.0.csv,size=2428] transfer relationship not specified
19:49:59 UTCERROR298edfeb-0173-1000-ffff-fffffab073a1
gcp6207dev05.example.com:9091SelectHiveQL[id=298edfeb-0173-1000-ffff-fffffab073a1] SelectHiveQL[id=298edfeb-0173-1000-ffff-fffffab073a1] failed to process session due to StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=fcc7293b-b97f-4e2c-81f8-75d684577b04,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1594824453797-6, container=default, section=6], offset=8441, length=2428],offset=0,name=aa00944a-f497-4814-97c6-b7287326fb01.0.csv,size=2428] transfer relationship not specified; Processor Administratively Yielded for 1 sec: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.FlowFileHandlingException: StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=fcc7293b-b97f-4e2c-81f8-75d684577b04,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1594824453797-6, container=default, section=6], offset=8441, length=2428],offset=0,name=aa00944a-f497-4814-97c6-b7287326fb01.0.csv,size=2428] transfer relationship not specified
```

Comment: Can you share your query, HiveConnectionPool config, etc.? That error message is definitely a bug (the flow file should be handled correctly either to success or failure) but I'd like to get an idea of what's happening so I can write up a Jira case to fix it.

Comment: Not sure @mattyb today I tried I did not face the same error, still amazed what happened, I will check and update you on the same thread if I found in the same link.